# How can i merge 4 module having almost same functionalities except their same collection with different filters as well as little bit design changes

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1

I have developed four modules. In that All the modules having almost same functionality of showing list from sales_flat_order table with different filters. It has some changes in design like on extra column in design table. that's it.

To remove redundancy of code, I want to merge my all that modules in one module. Is it correct way i am thinking in or i should put it as it is?

What are the ways in which i can optimize my code and reduce the level of redundancy in my code.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

Merging code has two problems:

1. it costs time
2. you don't know (except you have reliable tests) whether it works afterwards

This are the reasons agains what you want.

Having less code, means less code to understand and less code to maintain. This is always a win.

So if you still want to do this, I would throw all the code together in one module, make sure your grids, etc. has different names. Then you need to adjust all the collection names, etc. to use the same collection and you are done.

Somehow make sure, everything is still working.

Comment: ok. So can we use different collection in same block or model?

Comment: sure. You can even use the same collection class in two instances. Not sure wether I understand you.

Comment: thanks and no worries, Will try and let you know if it can be run successfully or having some errors.